# Validation with If-Else statement

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am trying to put add a validation condition to a combobox. I have been able to get it to work on other combo boxes, but here I am trying to essentially add 2 validaitons on one combobox. I am not familiar with how the whole validation process works and the order of operation. My code has become convoluted and need help sorting it out.

This is the code on the validation that I am working with:

```
functionvalidateSLBox(v){
    if(storeSpringLync.findExact('disp',
    v)>-1)returntrue;elsereturn'Notvalid';else{
        if(v=='DC'){
            cbSLBox.enable();
        }else{
            cbSLBox.disable();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `return` from a function, you exit at that point. Nothing else after it in the function executes, so you will never reach the second half of your function.

Also, one `else` matches to just one `if`. You have two `else`s here for one `if`.

You probably want something like this:

```
functionvalidateSLBox(v){
  if(v=='DC'){
    cbSLBox.enable();
  }else{
    cbSLBox.disable();
  }

  if(storeSpringLync.findExact('disp',v) > -1){
    return true;
  }else{
    return 'Not valid';
  }
}
```

This will allow you to both enable cbSLBox (whatever that is) while also returning true or Not valid... If this isn't what you want, you could use a `switch` statement or just nest the if statement. It really depends on what you want to do precisely, which is hard to tell from your code sample and description.